# AppleScript, InDesign errors

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to convert an existing swatch in InDesign to a new colour with AppleScript, and I'm finding it rather tough.

I'm getting an error code, thus:

```
error "Adobe InDesign CS5.5 got an error: Can’t set color of swatch \"CLIENT1\" of document id 12 to {0, 100, 100, 5}." number -10006 from color of swatch "CLIENT1" of document id 12
```

The code I'm using to adjust the swatch is this:

```
set color of swatch "CLIENT1" to c1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me crazy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The solution, for anyone else looking, is this:

```
set color value of color "CLIENT1" to c1
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This works in CS2 for a cmyk swatch:

```
set color value of swatch "CLIENT1" to {0, 20, 50, 10}
```

you have to set all 4 values. If it is an rgb swatch you'd only need 3 values.